# (Lisp) Counting Change code

Tags: loops, recursion, count, lisp, common-lisp

I've recently started learning lisp and i thought an interesting problem would be the Count Change algorithm which has been attempted many times however i've found it very difficult to even sort out how to approach this and thought i would try using loops but it just isn't working. I'll put my two useless attempts below but if anyone has any suggestions of even how i should be thinking about this problem in terms of lisp it would be really appreciated.
I would much prefer to use a recursive solution aswell.

I've been looking through the questions on here about counting change but they all tend to be object orientated while i need something more functional. 
It's not home work, just private study!

```
(defun dollar (amount)   
(let ((l 0) (j 0) (array (make-array '(5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 100000))) (results (make-array 50 :initial-element nil))
        (do (l 10 (+ l 1))
       (do ((= j (aref array l)) amount (+ j 1))
         (+ (aref array j) (- (aref results j) (aref array l))))))
                   ))

(defun coin-change (amount coins)
(cond ((< amount 0) 0)
      ((= amount 5) 1)
      ((null coins) 0)
      (t (+ (make-change-with-coins (- amount (car coins)) coins)
            (make-change-with-coins amount (cdr coins)))))
```

)

sample input would be (coin-change 20 '(5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 100000)) which would return 4

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_the_coins#Common_Lisp

Comment: Yeah i've already seen ta! it was useful however i dont think i understand it enough plus i would rather write it myself!

Answer (score 4):

Standard formatting helps getting the code structure right.  Reading some kind of documentation about a new language helps even more.

This is what you have written:

```
(defun dollar (amount)
  (let ((l 0)
        (j 0)
        (array (make-array '(5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 100000)))
        (results (make-array 50 :initial-element nil))
        (do (l 10 (+ l 1))
            (do ((= j (aref array l)) amount (+ j 1))
                (+ (aref array j) (- (aref results j) (aref array l))))))))
```

`Dollar` doesn't get the semantics right.  `Make-array` takes the dimensions as first argument, and you most likely wanted the `do` form as a body of the `let`.  I'd use a vector literal here.

```
(defun dollar (amount)
  (let ((l 0)
        (j 0)
        (array #(5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 100000))
        (results (make-array 50 :initial-element nil)))
    (do (l 10 (+ l 1))
        (do ((= j (aref array l)) amount (+ j 1))
            (+ (aref array j) (- (aref results j) (aref array l)))))))
```

`Do` takes first a list of bindings, then a form containing an end condition and return forms and finally forms that form a body.

```
(defun dollar (amount)
  (let ((l 0)
        (j 0)
        (array #(5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 5000 100000))
        (results (make-array 50 :initial-element nil)))
    (do ((l 10 (+ l 1)))
        (#| end condition here |#
         #| some more forms
         that return something |#)
      (do ((= j (aref array l)) ; uh, so this binds the variable "=" to j
                                ; and updates it to (aref array l) on iteration
           amount    ; an empty binding, initially nil
           (+ j 1))  ; binds the variable "+" to j and updates it to 1
          (+           ; tries to evaluate the variable "+" as a form...
           (aref array j)   ; no effect
           (- (aref results j) (aref array l)))))))  ; would return this
```

I tried to correct the shape of the outer `do` and annotated the inner `do`.  It makes no sense at all, as you can see.

```
(defun coin-change (amount coins)
  (cond ((< amount 0) 0)
        ((= amount 5) 1)
        ((null coins) 0)
        (t (+ (make-change-with-coins (- amount (car coins)) coins)
              (make-change-with-coins amount (cdr coins))))))
```

This looks at least semantically correct, but I cannot tell how it is supposed to work (and I don't know what `make-change-with-coins` does).

I think it would be prudent to perhaps read a good introductory book first (I like [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book)) and peruse the Common Lisp Hyperspec (CLHS).

Comment: oh sorry i had changed the name for the second! how stupid, was trying to make unique names because i had so many versions but i forgot to change the one at the top!

Comment: thanks very much for the tips on how to format it all correctly, i'm relatively new to common lisp so any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me what the first function is supposed to do.

The second one almost ok, this is a fixed version:

```
(defun coin-change (amount coins)
  (cond
    ((< amount 0) 0)
    ((= amount 0) 1)
    ((= (length coins) 0) 0)
    (t (+ (coin-change (- amount (first coins)) coins)
          (coin-change amount (rest coins))))))
```

The idea is:

- A negative amount cannot be matched (0 ways)
- Zero can be matched in exactly one way (not giving any coin)
- If amount is >0 and we've no coin types remaining then there are no ways
- Otherwise we can either A) give one piece of the first coin type and count how many ways we can match the remaining part, B) computing the ways  without using the first coin type. The answer is A+B

Note that this is going to give huge computing times for large amounts because it doesn't take advantage of the important fact that the number of ways to match a certain amount starting with a certain coin type doesn't depend on how we got to this amount (i.e. the past history).
By adding caching you can get a dynamic-programming solution that is much faster because does each computation only once.

Comment: Thanks so  much, hadn't realised what little i needed to change in the second to work, ill definitely work on it more! do you have any tips for caching? and also the first one i was basing of other example i had seen online written in java and but they used for loops an i tried to convert it! bit of a mess to be honest haha